# WordCloud ValueError: num must be 1 <= num <= 12, not 13

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, word-cloud

I want to make WordCloud, But After runing the snippet below I've had this

> Error ValueError: num must be 1 <= num <= 12, not 13

I think it's because I have many `rows` in the `dataframe`, more than 1000 rows.

```
# Let's make some word clouds!
# Terminal / Anaconda Prompt: conda install -c conda-forge wordcloud
from wordcloud import WordCloud

wc = WordCloud(stopwords=stop_words, background_color="white", 
colormap="Dark2", max_font_size=150, random_state=42)

# Reset the output dimensions
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [16, 6]

full_names = df['idi'].astype(str)
print(type(full_names))

# Create subplots for each row
for index, idi in enumerate(data.columns):
    wc.generate(Risk_data_clean.RISK[idi])

    plt.subplot(3, 4, index+1)
    plt.imshow(wc, interpolation="bilinear")
    plt.axis("off")
    plt.title(full_names[idi])

plt.show()
```

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace, so it become clear which line raises it.

Comment: Create a [mcve] for help here. Seems you have more than 12 columns in your dataframe.